# Kubelet stopped posting node status

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

Two of my cluster nodes gets `Kubelet stopped posting node status` in `kubectl describe node` sometimes. In logs of that nodes i see this:

```
Dec 11 12:01:03 alma-kube1 kubelet[946]: E1211 06:01:03.166998     946 controller.go:115] failed to ensure node lease exists, will retry in 6.4s, error: Get https://192.168.151.52:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/kube-node-lease/leases/alma-kube1?timeout=10s: read tcp 192.168.170.7:46824->192.168.151.52:6443: use of closed network connection
Dec 11 12:01:03 alma-kube1 kubelet[946]: W1211 06:01:03.167045     946 reflector.go:289] object-"kube-public"/"myregistrykey": watch of *v1.Secret ended with: very short watch: object-"kube-public"/"myregistrykey": Unexpected watch close - watch lasted less than a second and no items received
Dec 11 12:01:03 alma-kube1 kubelet[946]: W1211 06:01:03.167356     946 reflector.go:289] object-"kube-system"/"kube-router-token-bfzkn": watch of *v1.Secret ended with: very short watch: object-"kube-system"/"kube-router-token-bfzkn": Unexpected watch close - watch lasted less than a second and no items received
Dec 11 12:01:03 alma-kube1 kubelet[946]: W1211 06:01:03.167418     946 reflector.go:289] object-"kube-public"/"default-token-kcnfl": watch of *v1.Secret ended with: very short watch: object-"kube-public"/"default-token-kcnfl": Unexpected watch close - watch lasted less than a second and no items received
Dec 11 12:01:13 alma-kube1 kubelet[946]: E1211 06:01:13.329262     946 kubelet_node_status.go:385] Error updating node status, will retry: failed to patch status "{\"status\":{\"$setElementOrder/conditions\":[{\"type\":\"MemoryPressure\"},{\"type\":\"DiskPressure\"},{\"type\":\"PIDPressure\"},{\"type\":\"Ready\"}],\"conditions\":[{\"lastHeartbeatTime\":\"2019-12-11T06:01:03Z\",\"type\":\"MemoryPressure\"},{\"lastHeartbeatTime\":\"2019-12-11T06:01:03Z\",\"type\":\"DiskPressure\"},{\"lastHeartbeatTime\":\"2019-12-11T06:01:03Z\",\"type\":\"PIDPressure\"},{\"lastHeartbeatTime\":\"2019-12-11T06:01:03Z\",\"type\":\"Ready\"}]}}" for node "alma-kube1": Patch https://192.168.151.52:6443/api/v1/nodes/alma-kube1/status?timeout=10s: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Comment: It says the node could not connect the api server.

Comment: This might be a memory issue in your master

Comment: how to check it ?

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR

```
ssh <failing node>
sudo systemctl restart kubelet
```

I should have asked myself the magical words of "Have you tried turning it on and off?" I don't know what was causing my `kubelet` to fail, but I just `ssh` into the VM and restarted the `kubelet` service, and everything started working again.

Comment: this helped me, thanks a lot for sharing, my kubelet service went down, probably because  I restarted docker or did something wrong command, after starting it again, node came online - ready

Comment: What to do if I only get back: 
`Failed to restart kubelet.service: Unit kubelet.service not found.` ?

Update: `reboot` helped, but I did not learn whats going on.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) cannot patch its node status sometimes, more than 250 resources stay on the node, kubelet cannot watch more than 250 streams with kube-apiserver at the same time. Adjust kube-apiserver    `--http2-max-streams-per-connection` to 1000 to relieve the pain.

Take look on: [kubernetes-patch](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/74302).

**EDIT:**

Kubernetes uses client certificates, bearer tokens, an authenticating proxy, or HTTP basic auth to authenticate API requests through authentication plugins. As HTTP requests are made to the API server, plugins attempt to associate the following attributes with the request:

You can enable multiple authentication methods at once. You should usually use at least two methods:

- service account tokens for service accounts
- at least one other method for user authentication.

When multiple authenticator modules are enabled, the first module to successfully authenticate the request short-circuits evaluation. The API server does not guarantee the order authenticators run in.

Information about tokens you can find here: [tokens](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#putting-a-bearer-token-in-a-request).

You can also use a service account which is an automatically enabled authenticator that uses signed [bearer tokens](https://oauth.net/2/bearer-tokens/) to verify requests.

[Service accounts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#service-account-tokens) are usually created automatically by the API server and associated with pods running in the cluster through the ServiceAccount Admission Controller. Bearer tokens are mounted into pods at well-known locations, and allow in-cluster processes to talk to the API server.

Service account bearer tokens are perfectly valid to use outside the cluster and can be used to create identities for long standing jobs that wish to talk to the Kubernetes API. To manually create a service account, simply use the kubectl create serviceaccount (NAME) command. This creates a service account in the current namespace and an associated secret.

Secrets often hold values that span a spectrum of importance, many of which can cause escalations within Kubernetes (e.g. service account tokens) and to external systems. Even if an individual app can reason about the power of the secrets it expects to interact with, other apps within the same namespace can render those assumptions invalid.

To check tokens first you have to list secrets and then describe them (`$ kubectl describe secret secret-name`).

To lists secrets execute below command:

```
$ kubectl get secret
```

Secrets often hold values that span a spectrum of importance, many of which can cause escalations within Kubernetes (e.g. service account tokens) and to external systems. Even if an individual app can reason about the power of the secrets it expects to interact with, other apps within the same namespace can render those assumptions invalid.

More information you can find here: [secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/).

Comment: Ok, i will test this solution and write back

Comment: make changes on all overseer nodes and did not help

Comment: Could you I would check your certs / tokens?
Maybe read this over and double check your settings? https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/node/

Comment: How could i check my secrets and tokens ? Most likely it's a network problem, maybe on mine the cisco 2911 router...

Comment: I have updated my answer - with secret and tokens information. Does it solve your problem ? Please consider upvoting and accepting answer.